# iOS 12 load image from assets return nil

Tags: ios, iphone

```
+ (UIImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)aName
{
    
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bundleName" ofType:@"bundle"]];

    NSParameterAssert(aName);
    
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:aName inBundle:bundle compatibleWithTraitCollection:nil];
    return image;
    
}
```

Assets.car file is in bundleName.bundle, iOS >= 13 can load image from assets, iOS <= 12 load image return nil, how can i resolve this problems?

Comment: `imageNamed` already exists. Give your method a different name.